# What are good practices for class hinting in JSON?

Tags: json, serialization, deserialization, standards

I would like to know if there are preferred ways to exchange custom objects serialized as JSON, so that both ends can get a (rough) idea on how to deal with the values exchanged.

I guess this is language-dependent, and probably defeats the purpose of using JSON as a "standard" exchange format in the first place, but if we, *at least*, consider using the same language on both sides, how would you do this?

A typical use case would be for example: how to exchange date time objects without resorting too much on ad-hoc code when serializing/deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what language you are targeting, however give a try to
http://www.servicestack.net/

If a robust Client and Server webservice framework, which works around with classes and objects